# Magmi removing product relations on import

Tags: php, magento, csv, magmi

I just found out a problem when using Magmi to import products into a Magento environment.

The Magento installation has 2 different stores on 2 different domains, all running from a single Magento instance. Both stores have the same products, but require are small difference in the product data, as sale prices may differ based on the store it's being used in.

When the products for de default store are being updated (store set to `admin`, website set to `default` in the CSV file) it seems like Magmi deletes all product relations for this product. When the relations are being restored manually and the same CSV file is used to update again, but the store and website are being set to a different value, the relations stay untouched.

I have verified the CSV file as being correct, as all the data is being imported properly. The product relater plugin has been switched off to test if that does the trick, but the same thing keeps happening. There is no column `re_skus` or `xre_skus` in the CSV file which may be causing the problem.

How can I make sure that Magmi keeps the relations the way they are instead of removing them everytime the products get updated?

Magento version is 1.8.1.0 and Magmi version is 0.7.20.

Comment: Did you find a solution? We can chat here https://gitter.im/develop/magmi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "admin" store is a value that tells  => consider all following values to be "common" to all stores.
Depending on the order of import of your files (or lines in the CSV if you are using a single file), the "admin" will also assume "remove all previous store specific associations for the data of this line" (for all data that may have a store view scope).

So it's just a "import" partitioning problem.

Create one file for "common" values for all stores (this may include product relation)
Create one file for "store specific" values (ie: columns will only be sku + store specific attributes)

Maybe you could also create a file for "associations".

Or use the same file within 3 magmi import profiles, filtering with "import limiter" and or "value replacer" but this is only for optimizing edition time & could be a bit tricky.

This could help solving your problem.

Comment: So if I'm reading your answer correctly, this means that we can't update the data on "admin" level without removing all relations? This actually doesn't make sense to me, as I would like to keep on using a full CSV file for every import.

Comment: Faced with this problem as well. But worse is that I have no control of which websites,store values are in the import. I need "append" line functionality for store relation. @dweeves could you point to the code where store relation happens?